# Order problem in nilpotent groups

Tags: combinatorial-group-theory, nilpotent-groups, word-problem

Let $G$ be a f.g. nilpotent group. I wanted to know if the order problem (given $g \in G$, deciding if there exists $n$ s.t. $g^n=e$) is decidable in $G$? In such a group, the word problem is decidable and we know from Blackburn that so is the conjugacy problem (deciding if $g$ and $h$ are conjugate). Thanks!